# Join three tables with MAX function, table structure a bit complex

Tags: mysql, sql

Without changing tables structure how can I achieve the following:

I have three tables: `student`, `book_price` and `book_data`.
I want to display the details of `max(price)` of each student.

**student table**

```
student_id   student_name
    1           Sarah
    2           John
    3           Peter
```

**book_price table**

```
price_id    student_id      book_id     price
    105         1           464         15.07
    106         1           557         26.80
    205         2           329         16.48
    207         2           331         11.05
    217         3           202         19.95
```

**book_data table**

```
book_id     book_name           book_image
    464     Goodnight Moon      site_url_1
    557     The Snowy Day       site_url_4
    329     Harry Potter        site_url_2
    331     Green Egg           site_url_5
    202     The Hobbit          site_url_3
```

The result should be:

```
student_id    student_name      price       book_name       book_image
    1           Sarah           26.80       The Snowy Day   site_url_4      
    2           Peter           19.95       The Hobbit      site_url_3
    2           John            16.48       Harry Potter    site_url_2
```

Comment: This is a simple problem of `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
SELECT st.student_id, 
    st.student_name, 
    bp.price, 
    bd.Book_name, 
    bd.book_image
FROM Student st
INNER JOIN book_price as bp ON st.student_id = bp.student_id
INNER JOIN book_data as bd ON bp.book_id = bd.book_id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Student_id, MAX(price) AS price
            FROM book_price
            GROUP BY Student_id) AS t ON bp.student_id = t.student_id
AND bp.price = t.price
ORDER BY bp.price DESC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
student_id  student_name    price   Book_name        book_image
1           Sarah           26.8    The Snowy Day    site_url_4
3           Peter           19.95   The Hobbit       site_url_3
2           John            16.48   Harry Potter     site_url_2
```

Link To the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d4d0d/10

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bba1/42/0)

```
select student_id,student_name,price,book_id,book_image from (
  select *,
      CASE student_id 
          WHEN @curId THEN
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 
          ELSE @curRow :=1
      END AS rank,
      @curId := student_id AS student_id2
  from (
    select stu.student_id ,
        stu.student_name,
        max(bp.price) price,
        bd.book_id,
        bd.book_image
    from book_price bp
    left join student stu on stu.student_id = bp.student_id
    left join book_data bd on bd.book_id = bp.book_id 
    group by stu.student_id,stu.student_name
        ,bd.book_id,bd.book_image
    ORDER BY student_id,price DESC
  ) T
  JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curId := 0) r
)T2
where rank = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Above query is giving Wrong Result

Comment: Match your result with the expected result and tell me is it right??

Comment: yes,your answer is right
i I did not consider each student's max price

Comment: add a order price just be ok : )